# LIMIT issue in MySQLi Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have three PHP APIs which have the below queries:

API 1:

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by id LIMIT 0,700";
```

API 2:

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by id LIMIT 701,1400";
```

API 3:

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by id LIMIT 1401,2100";
```

I want take 700 records in each API. For example,

0 to 700 in API 1,

701 to 1400 in API 2 and

1401 to 2100 in API 3 (like shown above).

API 1 is working fine but API 2 and 3 are missing a result.

Why is this occurring and how do I correct it?

Comment: use offset and limit.

Comment: What do you mean by mixing result?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra how can I use it ? Can You post answer with example ?

Comment: Ooooooh *Mixing result* is supposed to be ***Missing** result*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API 1

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by id LIMIT 0,700";
```

API 2

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by id LIMIT 700,700";
```

API 3

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by id LIMIT 1400,700";
```

**Explanation**

> Mysql also provides a way to handle this: by using OFFSET.

**The SQL query below says "return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)":**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";
```

**You could also use a shorter syntax to achieve the same result:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10";
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10ff28/7

Comment: Hi! in second api I do not need from 701 ? because my id starting from 1

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in the limit talks about the size of the rows you need so in your case since you need a chunk of 700, the second part after comma will always be 700.

So your queries will be like

```
LIMIT 0,700";   //for api 1

LIMIT 700,700"; //for api 2

LIMIT 1400,700"; //for api 3
```

Comment: Hi! in second api I do not need from 701 ? because my id starting from 1

Comment: are you missing any record? may you deleted any record that's why it misses the row

Comment: its work from id 1 to 700 or starting from id 1 to till 700 count ?

Comment: select count(*) from table where id<701 and the total should be 700 if not that means you are missing the rows

Comment: in case of 700 onward, the condition will change to id>700 and id<1401

Comment: I do not need its on id based....I want take first 700 row than 701 to 1400 and 1401 to 2100

Comment: I need it in first API as 0,700 ? or 1,700 ? sorry for silly question. Thanks

Comment: 0,700 for first

Answer (score 0):

> The LIMIT keyword of is used to limit the number of rows returned from
>
> a result set. The LIMIT number can be any number from zero (0) going
>
> upwards. When zero (0) is specified as the limit, no rows are returned
>
> from the result set. The OFF SET value allows us to specify which row
>
> to start from retrieving data It can be used in conjunction with the
>
> SELECT, UPDATE OR DELETE commands LIMIT keyword syntax

```
SELECT {fieldname(s) | *} FROM tableName(s) [WHERE condition] LIMIT N;
```

In your case it will be :

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 order by id LIMIT 700,700";

$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 order by id LIMIT 1400,700";
```